# Springboot: Not printing JSON to web application

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a simple web application and I am trying to get JSON object to print but I when I go to the link, I get the **WhiteLabel Error Page**

Here is my Java code for controller:

```
@Controller
public class WsdlController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/getReport", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> getMyResponse() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String url = "this url has JSON data";
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL(url).openStream()));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(json, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
}
```

So when I run it and go to `localhost:8080/getReport` I get this error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Aug 16 11:31:21 EDT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation
```

Comment: What is the error showing up in the console? There is normally some insight that is shown around why Spring returned an error.